# How to send an event to all running instances of a AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda, broadcast

I have a Lambda function whose configuration is located in an external source (say S3).

In order to save some computing time, the function loads and keeps in memory the configuration at first execution.

I want to be able to tell **all running instances** of this Lambda function to reload the configuration on demand.

In the snippet below, the Lambda function reloads the configuration when the event has an attribute 'reload'. But obviously only one of the running instances gets the event.

- How can I send the event to all running instances?
- Is there a way to **broadcast** an event?
- Is there another way to tackle the problem?

```
// Function to process events
var processEvent = function(event,callback) {
  // process event
}

// Function to update configuration
var config; // global object representing configuration
var updateConfiguration = function(callback) {
  // ... load asynchronously from S3
}

// Handle events
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  if (event.reload) {
    updateConfiguration(callback);   // load configuration
  } else if (!config) {
    updateConfiguration(function() { // load configuration
      processEvent(event,callback);  // ... then process event
    });
  } else {
    processEvent(event,callback);    // process event directly
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **no capability** to send messages to AWS Lambda containers. When they are not running, they are effectively "frozen" with no compute happening.

The closest option would be to **have the handler check somewhere** (parameter store?) whenever a function is invoked, to see whether it should reload.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could subscribe to an SNS-Topic and send the event through this topic. The function inside your lambda that subscribes to this topic can then update the `config` variable.

Keep in mind that lambda functions have some special caching behaviour regarding global variables. You can read more on this topic here: https://medium.com/tensult/aws-lambda-function-issues-with-global-variables-eb5785d4b876